# Android custom dialog onclick listener error

Tags: android, layout, onclick, dialog, listener

i am trying to implemet own layout on dialog window. But i don't know how to create on click listner, because i defined dialog inside another class, which has another layout. How can i "find" buttons from dialog xml in another class with another layout.

Here is code :

```
public void dialog(String text){
    final String karta = text;
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Terminal.this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null);
    mBuilder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String akcia = "Prichod";
            pridajZaznam(karta, akcia);
        }
    });

    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String akcia = "Odchod prestavka";
            pridajZaznam(karta, akcia);
        }
    });

    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String akcia = "Odchod";
            pridajZaznam(karta, akcia);
        }
    });

    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String akcia = "Prichod prestavka";
            pridajZaznam(karta, akcia);
        }
    });
}
```

This method is inside class Terminal which have own layout, but dialog uses activity_dialog.xml layout file. Dialog shows correctly if i dont use listners, they cause null pointer exception...

Thanks for any answers !

Comment: where do you declare buttons b1, b2 ...

Comment: inside class , maybe i should declare them insde dialog method ?

Comment: `View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null);`

This view contain view-hierarchy from `activity_dialog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b1);` instead of `b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);`

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create a custom dialog
1. create layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
 xmls:https://....
<TextView 
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:layout_width= "match_parent"
android:id="@+id/myText/>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:layout_width= "match_parent"
android:orientation = "horizontal"
>
<Button
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:layout_width= "match_parent"
android:id="@+id/positiveBtn/>
Button
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:layout_width= "match_parent"
android:id="@+id/negativeBtn/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then call it from your Activity

```
Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(context);
myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dilog_layout);
Button positiveBtn  = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.positiveBtn);
Button negativeBtn= myDialog.findViewById(R.id.negativeBtn);
TextView tv= myDialog.findViewById(R.id.myText);
myText.setText("WWhat you want");
negativeBtn.setOnClickListenr(new OnClickListener....);
 myDialog.show();
```